# Configure WiX project to install multiple versions, but remove same minor version

Tags: wix, wix3

I need to configure my WiX project to be able to install multiple minor versions of the product. IE: I can have 1.0, 1.1 and 1.3 installed. If I try to install 1.2, it will work, but if I try it with 1.1, it will uninstall the previous 1.1 installation before proceeding.

So far, this is what I have in my `Upgrade` tag:

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.MajorMinorVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes" 
        Maximum="$(var.VersionNumber)" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="OLDERMINORFOUND"/>
</Upgrade>
```

`UpgradeCode` is a guid defined in my wxi file and `MajorMinorVersion` is the same as `VersionNumber`, but with the build at 0 (1.1.0 when the version is 1.1.12).

I'm guessing that I have two possibilities:

I make another `UpgradeVersion` tag or update the current one to have the maximum at the next minor version and exclude it from the search:

```
<UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.MajorMinorVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes" 
        Maximum="$(var.NextMinorVersion)" IncludeMaximum="no"/>
```

Using a custom action to set `NextMinorVersion` somehow. Maybe using a property instead.

Or, change the UpgradeCode manually each time the minor version changes. Or have the first few characters of the guid represent the version and the rest be unique? I doubt that's a good idea though...

So basically, what would be the best way to accomplish this, in the hopes of having only one setup project for all versions?

**EDIT**

I've looked into the `MajorUpgrade` tag, but I don't think I can configure it to have many minor versions at the same time. Any light on this is appreciated.

I've also looked into making a preprocessor extension that would manipulate the version number using functions, so I could do this:

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <UpgradeVersion Property="OLDERMINORFOUND"
        Minimum="$(var.MajorMinorVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes" 
        Maximum="$(myprefix.NextMinor($(var.VersionNumber)))" IncludeMaximum="no"/>
</Upgrade>
```

See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wrote an extension as per the WiX manual ([Part 1](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extension_development_simple_example.htm) and [Part 2](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extension_development_preprocessor.htm)).

I made a preprocessor extension that takes a version number string (ex: 1.2.3.4) and manipulates the version by parsing and splitting the string.

So now I can write this in my .wxs file:

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
    <UpgradeVersion Property="SAMEMINORFOUND" OnlyDetect="no"
        Minimum="$(var.MajorMinorVersion).0" IncludeMinimum="yes" 
        Maximum="$(version.NextMinor($(var.VersionNumber)))" IncludeMaximum="no" />
    <UpgradeVersion Property="OLDERVERSIONFOUND" OnlyDetect="yes"
        Maximum="$(var.MajorMinorVersion).0" IncludeMaximum="no"/>
    <UpgradeVersion Property="NEWERVERSIONFOUND" OnlyDetect="yes"
        Minimum="$(version.NextMinor($(var.VersionNumber)))" IncludeMinimum="yes"/>
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallValidate"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Where `version.NextMinor` is a call to my preprocessor extension.

So my installer will only detect installations of the product unless the minor versions match, where it will be uninstalled.